# converting string format to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am not able to convert the string to DATE format

```
select CONVERT(DATE, '8/17/2016', 103)
```

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

what can we do to resolve this
thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: just change 103 to 101

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need that style, It is the one causing the error. Just `CAST/CONVERT` it to date. Try this

```
select CONVERT(DATE, '8/17/2016')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `cast` also

```
  select cast( '8/17/2016' as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '8/17/2016', 101)
```

Comment: please, consider adding an explanation, even a short one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '8/17/2016', 111)
```

Comment: please consider adding an explanation, even a short one. Thanks!